# how to count same values are exists in my record

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem: I am not able to count how many occurrences of a number are in my table

**Example:** Suppose my table has records like this:

```
number
 2
 4
 6
 2
 2
 4
 2
```

I want the following: If `2`  exists 4 times it will be count and display record 2 exists 4 times
and `2` exists 4 exists 2 times and 6 exists 1 times.

Please help me

Comment: this is a basic sql question. I suggest you to get your hands on a good sql book or read a good sql tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `number`, COUNT(*) as TotalRecords FROM records GROUP BY `number` ORDER BY `number` ASC
```